# Scroll bar does not appear in my interface

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add an horizental scroll bar to my table with CSS but it does not appear

Here is my html code :

```
 <div class="cwc-table">    
            <div class="scrollable">
                <table style="width:100%" 
                data-show-columns="true"
                data-minimum-count-columns="2"
                data-checkbox-header="true"
                data-search="false" 
                data-pagination="true" 
                data-sort-order="asc" 
                data-show-export="true"
                data-export-types="['excel', 'csv']"
                data-export-options='{
                    fileName: "export",
                    worksheetName: "export",
                    csvSeparator: ";",
                    csvUseBOM: true 
                 }' >
            </table>    
            </div>  
        </div>
```

And my css is very simple :

```
.scrollable {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

My interface looks like this :

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9WeB.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse you're table width is 100%. make it 110 and then check. And if you want scrollbar inside table assign scrollable class to table

Comment: It does not change anything unfortunately